# How to make checked QPushButton look the same as when it's pressed?

Tags: qt, checked, qtstylesheets, qpushbutton

How to make checked QPushButton look same as when it's pressed? Like this:

[image]

This is a picture of the pressed button. What should I write in stylesheet?

```
"QPushButton:pressed {"
 "background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,"
                                       "stop: 0 #dadbde, stop: 1 #f6f7fa);}"  
"QPushButton:checked {"
 "background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,"
                                   "stop: 0 #dadbde, stop: 1 #f6f7fa);"
 "border: none;}"
```

I tried to write border as none, but I just got this:

[image]

And I need borders stay the same.

Comment: Do you want the `QPushButton` to always look as it is being pressed? If so, why don't you use [`setCheckable(true)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#checkable-prop) and [`setChecked(true)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#checked-prop)?

Comment: Try to set borders for all selectors, not only for `QPushButton:checked`

Comment: Point is that I need these borders, how on first picture. And I need the same background color. If I don't set border - none, than I lose my background color. It becomes strange, something white and transperent.

Answer (score 0):

This is because on default QPushButton:pressed has its own border which is set natively based on your OS.

To get around this, you can set the QPushButton:pressed border to something very similar to how it looks now, then set the same border for QPushButton:checked.

It seems to me that it is a 1px wide, black, inset border, so something like this should do the trick.

```
"QPushButton:pressed {"
"background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,"
                                       "stop: 0 #dadbde, stop: 1 #f6f7fa);" 
"border: 1px inset black;}" 

"QPushButton:checked {"
 "background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,"
                                   "stop: 0 #dadbde, stop: 1 #f6f7fa);"
 "border: 1px inset black;}"
```